# Jquery - mouse over -> fade in/out // click -> opacity 100% // other click -> opacity 60

Tags: jquery, onclick, fadein, fadeout

I'm working on a website with jquery and thumbnails.

When the page is loaded all the thumbnails have to be on 60% of opacity. As soon as you go with your mouse over a thumb it needs to fade to 100%, if you move with your mouse out the thumbnail needs to fade back up on 60% of opacity.

When the user clicks on a thumbnail it has to stay at 100% of opacity. As soon as the user clickss on another thumbnail the 'old' thumbnail has to fade back to 60% and the 'new' one has to stay at 100%. (it already has 100% opacity because you go with your mouse over it).

This is the code I have so far:

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
    $("#mycarousel li").fadeTo(1, 0.6);

    $("#mycarousel li").hover(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(350, 1.0);
        $(this).addClass('Active');
    }, function () {
        $("this:not('.Active')").fadeTo(350, 0.6);
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    var activeOpacity   = 1.0,
        inactiveOpacity = 0.6,
        fadeTime = 350,
        clickedClass = "selected",
        thumbs = "#mycarousel li";

    $(thumbs).fadeTo(1, inactiveOpacity);

    $(thumbs).hover(
        function(){
            $(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
        },
        function(){
            // Only fade out if the user hasn't clicked the thumb
            if(!$(this).hasClass(clickedClass)) {
                $(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, inactiveOpacity);
            }
        });
     $(thumbs).click(function() {
         // Remove selected class from any elements other than this
         var previous = $(thumbs + '.' + clickedClass).eq();
         var clicked = $(this);
         if(clicked !== previous) {
             previous.removeClass(clickedClass);
         }
         clicked.addClass(clickedClass).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
     });
});
```

Comment: Glad it worked. You could also consider accepting this answer if it worked properly to show that it has been solved. Thanks =)